# Angular4 select options and show data in UI from REST calls

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-router

I need to create a webpage with dropdown having values ALL , Test1 & Test 2 respectively.

Now if user is selecting :

```
 All ---> localhost:8080/testcases

 Test1 --> localhost:4200/testcases?module=Test1

 Test2 ->localhost:4200/testcases?module=Test2
```

I have created below module.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Testcase } from '../testcase';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-module',
   templateUrl: './module.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./module.component.css']
})
export class ModuleComponent implements OnInit {
testCases: Testcase[];
types= ["ALL", "Test1", "Test2"];

getTestcases() {
  return this.dataService.getTestcases().then(testCases => this.testCases = testCases);
 }

 constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

 ngOnInit() {

 }

 }
```

corresponding html file:

```
   <div> type:
         <select>
               <option *ngFor="let i of type">{{i}}</option>
         </select>
   </div>
```

Here, getTestcases() is returning me all the correct response for

localhost:4200/testcases(If I am calling this from corresponding testcase component),but I am not sure here in module component how to use with this dropdown

call,Since its my first interaction with Angular4,I am totally stuck and unable

to move further,need your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
 <select>
       <option *ngFor="let i of types">{{i}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: yes,i want to know how to pass correct data as in all 3 cases ,there would be different api calls and json results,like for 'ALL' how to parse the value returned by getTestcases()

Comment: use ngModel with ngModelChange

Comment: also for types(in module.component.ts),hv to create key pair like (ALL, getTestcases()),is it?

Comment: yeah you can create an interface for that

Comment: if possible can u paste any reference or sample code snippet

Comment: somehow managed to unblock myself,although its not a good way (just managed to get data using rest calls):

ts file:
  selectChangeHandler (event: any) {
     this.getTestcases();
    }
  }
html:

 <select (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
        <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
    </select>
  <!--   <p><span>You selected: </span><b>{{selectedDay}}</b></p> -->
     <a *ngFor="let testcase of testCases" "  class="col-1-4">
    <div>
      <h4>{{testcase.name}} ---- {{testcase.desc}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</article>

Comment: did the answer help